# Getting “Enter passphrase for key” for a linux machine from shell script

Tags: openssh

Context: Want to automate a process which requires a connection to Linux vm machine from code running on AWS cloud.

Code Snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -i LinuxVM.ppk testuser@<ipadress> 'df -h'.
```

Result: When I am running the above shell script I am getting an error "Enter passphrase for key 'LinuxVM.ppk':"

The same PPK file I am using to connect the remote vm through 'putty' and I am through.

While creating the PPK from puttygen file I have not given any phrases.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH does not support Putty keys (`.ppk`).

You will need to convert your key. How this is done is described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygen-windows-into-key-pairs-us